# How would bacteria go about forming a multicellular organism?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology

**I am working on a planet with life composed of prokaryotic cells, like bacteria from earth but which have formed large organisms.** What perplexes me is that I haven't found a single example about bacteria forming a larger creature.

So I was wondering if there was a way for this to happen?

The goal is to get complex lifeforms like plants and animals. If there are limitations on size or other factors I would gladly want to know, so I can go about designing my fauna properly.

Comment: The thing is, prokaryotic cells are (by and large) very much smaller than eukaryotic cells; you need *a lot* of them just to get to the size of typical [protist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protist) (= eukaryotic monocellular organism).

Answer (score 5):

**There are colonial prokaryotes.**

[image: nostoc]
[source](https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?seq_num=260004&one=T) .  Used with permission.

Nostoc (aka star jelly) is a colonial cyanobacteria.  They get as big as small plants.  The component cells are held together by matrix they secrete.  There must be some sort of communication between them to organize the shape of the colony.  I like Nostoc because of the possibility that it might fall from the sky with meterorites, but there are many other examples of colonial prokaryotes - both eubacteria and archaebacteria.

You could then take a page from the book of other single celled organisms that agglomerate into colonies to see what emergent properties they acquire.  Slime molds are eukaryotes and live as amoebas, but then come together to form large masses of rolling slime.  Or if it is not cheating you could have the prokaryotes form commensal colonies with fungi or algae.  Here is a sweet tree lungwort - a three way commensal of fungus, algae and cyanobacteria.

[image: tree lungwort]

my own photo.

Of course all non AI-readers of these musings currently reside in examples of commensal team-ups with prokaryotes.  The cellular energy powering our bodies comes from prokaryotic mitochondria, which domesticated some lumbering eukaryotes in the distant past and formed them into the fortresses which are our bodies.  Animals and plants are just sweet rides for their master prokaryotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me this, I read science articles as a hobby so there are things I tend to overlook. Also very nice picture you've got there.

Answer (score 3):

The first step would probably be to form something akin of a biofilm: a community of unicellular organisms thriving in the same environment.

The next step would be a separation of roles and tasks: some of them on the outside could specialize in protecting/shielding those inside, some other could specialize in digesting nutrients for the rest of the community, some other could take on the task of reproducing.

Afterwards one can come up with interaction with the outer environment, motion and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an issue...... Colonial bacteria, like Myxobacteria and Cyanobacteria are already complex enough that they have many of the traits that are needed for true multicellularity-- Intercellular communication, Cell-to-Cell adhesion ,Cell differentiation, and even things like a definite germline (Myxobacteria form Myxospores--ECM coated clumps of several thousand cells that functions just like the spores of fungi. or in this case, almost like the seeds of plants since the Myxospores are multicellular; Cyanobacteria form Akinetes-- strands of the colonial bacterium that undergoes a form of cryptobiosis and leaves the colony to seed new growths).

So it's not unreasonable that such processes could not be taken to the logical next step in order to create multicellular prokaryotic lifeforms (Though they probably won't have a definite lifespan, as Bacterial chromosomes are circular and therefore have no hayflick limit to limit the lifespan of a colony/multicellular individual), since Multicellularity is all about how cells communicate with each other and interact, and not so much about the internal structure of the cells themselves.

Fun fact: Acetnomycetes, a type of multicellular bacteria, was long mistaken for fungi until they realized that they were suspectible to Antibiotics like Penicillin-- classifying them as being Bacteria rather than True Fungi.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinomycetales